# Was experimenting with Timelock transactions its now past the time of the timelock expiration however I still get the (non-final) Error

Tags: transactions

I am getting the Non-Final error on some timelocked BTC even through it is past the time set. I have searched around and seen someone post that this can happen with unconfirmed transactions. My original timelock transaction is confirmed.

Here is the original locked transaction 38eVWPirWs7j54Y8FtuHY9RZ3aXnMaEijY

I used a guide located here and followed the steps accurately
https://steemit.com/bitcoin/@daan/how-to-create-time-locked-transactions-with-bitcoin-free-bitcoins-inside

and used a local copy of coinb.in

---

yeah I suspect its because I used a BC1 address and not a 1/3 address as per the guide. Ill give all the details if anyone wants to investigate if you solve it you can spend the transaction its like 3$ usd please let me know how to do it properly next time and what worked. Thanks

Redeem script
0490a87065b17521031c924ba9400b2f2fec7c167b4c4bf5e6d6a691f36af8633e50ae36d3fbb34ef0ac

Unsigned transaction
0100000001edad9d61ba76a2c47a6c46a1f024139f770d0519f30792260a8f5e38285d5e00000000002a0490a87065b17521031c924ba9400b2f2fec7c167b4c4bf5e6d6a691f36af8633e50ae36d3fbb34ef0acfdffffff016022000000000000160014705becd1fde498c9b8fd1b634036f8a8b24d3a8090a87065

Signed transaction
0100000001edad9d61ba76a2c47a6c46a1f024139f770d0519f30792260a8f5e38285d5e000000000073473044022077b81991d3055e13705eeccad01949261518530abef53ae65de5a05db0f0060802207eb0259f77ca510270ccd65d3b8fc2144c51b3c3fcc7f65d947c3d2e13821d78012a0490a87065b17521031c924ba9400b2f2fec7c167b4c4bf5e6d6a691f36af8633e50ae36d3fbb34ef0acfdffffff016022000000000000160014705becd1fde498c9b8fd1b634036f8a8b24d3a8090a87065

Original encoding address

031c924ba9400b2f2fec7c167b4c4bf5e6d6a691f36af8633e50ae36d3fbb34ef0
(bc1qjkg4tvxw8t2zwq9ullvgkq939ranns447macwx) Suspect this address is what made it not work

Private key for above address
L35XvrBVMfChdZLvEuJdpgaadSMny4dTpKqCSASC4Ykr8Za6rqCv

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the original locked transaction 38eVWPirWs7j54Y8FtuHY9RZ3aXnMaEijY

That isn't a transaction-ID it is an address.

That address is associated with only one transaction so far. The transaction ID is 005e5d28385e8f0a269207f319050d779f1324f0a1466c7ac4a276ba619daded

That transaction has a locktime of 0 according to a blockchain explorer

[blockchair.com shows this transactions](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/005e5d28385e8f0a269207f319050d779f1324f0a1466c7ac4a276ba619daded) "raw TX" data in JSON as

```
{
    "txid": "005e5d28385e8f0a269207f319050d779f1324f0a1466c7ac4a276ba619daded",
    "hash": "8edd5bbdcdfe2bb7b7ca8b2f6b4808f1fd1023b5da91f6802b51fd9b46e8cd75",
    "version": 1,
    "size": 224,
    "vsize": 142,
    "weight": 566,
    "locktime": 0,
    "vin": [
        {
            "txid": "0f862b7e37471bc6481d3066fc06a2a8eb58b5b482077c024af0d0f3b9ac776c",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "",
                "hex": ""
            },
            "txinwitness": [
                "3045022100f58be5c334fbdeb582a6bd2f106520316fe5f42e365748e5fac6c60527f43696022067753fc4664b5dea501baddeb59f267d833654358b1e7a8d82cfe406b92270c101",
                "02cd50ac8a15a5ebd7c211dd28792901a77fe9e60b5ebe84f1cc42e31c18235e2a"
            ],
            "sequence": 0
        }
    ],
    "vout": [
        {
            "value": 0.0001,
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "OP_HASH160 4c4ea881d3c7767e25718fcc93714627fd989ff3 OP_EQUAL",
                "hex": "a9144c4ea881d3c7767e25718fcc93714627fd989ff387",
                "address": "38eVWPirWs7j54Y8FtuHY9RZ3aXnMaEijY",
                "type": "scripthash",
                "addresses": [
                    "38eVWPirWs7j54Y8FtuHY9RZ3aXnMaEijY"
                ],
                "reqSigs": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "value": 0.00016763,
            "n": 1,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "0 30910f8b05507355168cf8d9f5bbf35a85d16898",
                "hex": "001430910f8b05507355168cf8d9f5bbf35a85d16898",
                "address": "bc1qxzgslzc92pe4295vlrvltwlnt2zaz6ycvy8w3f",
                "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
                "addresses": [
                    "bc1qxzgslzc92pe4295vlrvltwlnt2zaz6ycvy8w3f"
                ],
                "reqSigs": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that

```
    "locktime": 0,
```

AFAIK locktime determines the *earliest* a transaction can be included in a block, it doesn't guarantee the transaction gets included in a block at the specified time or at the specified height.